# Buscar y obtener coordenadas X e Y de un elemento en una matriz bidimensional

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo la siguiente lista:

```
laberinto = [
    ['*', '*', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|'],
    ['|', '*', '*', '*', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|'],
    ['|', '|', '|', '*', '|', '|', '*', '*', '*', '|'],
    ['|', '|', '|', '*', '|', '|', '*', '|', '*', '|'],
    ['|', '|', '|', '*', '*', '*', '*', '|', '*', '*'],
    ['|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '*'],
    ['|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '*', '*', '*'],
    ['|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '*', '|', '|'],
    ['|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '*', '|', '|'],
    ['|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '*', '*', '*'],
]
```

Quisiera obtener las coordenadas X y Y de cada uno de los *, he podido recorrer toda la matriz con 2 ciclos `for` pero no logro entender como obtener sus coordenadas, he usado e intentado con el método `index` pero solo obtengo la coordenada X de un solo elemento.

Comment: KevinBueno bienvenido a [es.so]. Te recomiendo que te mires [tour] y [ask] para conocer un poco como funciona el sitio y como hacer preguntas que sean bienvenidas. Aunque se intuye el código que estas intentado con los dos `for`  + `list.index` te recomiendo que siempre agregues el código que tienes, esto hará que tu pregunta sea mejor aceptada y facilita que te respondan adecuadamente. Igualmente es bueno que expliques el problema concreto que tienes con el código que ya tienes. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema con `list.index` es que solo te va a retornar solo el primer elemento que encuentre de tu fila, lo cual dificulta la cosa. En vez de `index` usa un condicional del tipo `if elemento == '*'`.

Una opción simple y eficiente es usar `enumerate` en compresión de listas o generadores.

```
laberinto = [
    ['*', '*', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|'],
    ['|', '*', '*', '*', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|'],
    ['|', '|', '|', '*', '|', '|', '*', '*', '*', '|'],
    ['|', '|', '|', '*', '|', '|', '*', '|', '*', '|'],
    ['|', '|', '|', '*', '*', '*', '*', '|', '*', '*'],
    ['|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '*'],
    ['|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '*', '*', '*'],
    ['|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '*', '|', '|'],
    ['|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '*', '|', '|'],
    ['|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '*', '*', '*'],
]

busqueda = ((x,  y) for x,  row in enumerate(laberinto)
                        for y,  elemento in enumerate(row)  if elemento == '*')

for e in busqueda:
    print(e)
```

**Salida**

```
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
(2, 6)
(2, 7)
(2, 8)
(3, 3)
(3, 6)
(3, 8)
(4, 3)
(4, 4)
(4, 5)
(4, 6)
(4, 8)
(4, 9)
(5, 9)
(6, 7)
(6, 8)
(6, 9)
(7, 7)
(8, 7)
(9, 7)
(9, 8)
(9, 9)
```

En este caso se crea un generador que retorna una tupla con los indices de cada elemento que es '*'.

Usamos dos `for` para recorrer la matriz, `enumerate` retorna una tupla con el indice y el valor por cada elemento de la lista.

Si quieres una lista con todos los indices directamente, simplemente haces:

```
busqueda = [(x,  y) for x,  row in enumerate(laberinto)
                        for y,  elemento in enumerate(row)  if elemento == '*']
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, dado que es una matriz cuadra `N x N` bastaría obtener la dimensión de la matriz `laberinto` con `len` y aplicar dos bucles anidados indexando la matriz por filas (`i`) y columnas (`j`) para identificar con un condicional `if`, si el carácter (`*`) está en la celda respectiva:

```
dim = len(laberinto) # Es una matriz cuadrada N x N

for j in range(0,dim):    #columna
  for i in range(0,dim):  #fila
    if '*' in laberinto[i][j]: print('({0}, {0})'.format(i,j))

# Impresion
# (0, 0)
# (0, 0)
# (1, 1)
# (1, 1)
# (1, 1)
# (2, 2)
# (3, 3)
# (4, 4)
# (4, 4)
# (4, 4)
# (2, 2)
# (3, 3)
# (4, 4)
# (2, 2)
# (6, 6)
# (7, 7)
# (8, 8)
# (9, 9)
# (2, 2)
# (3, 3)
# (4, 4)
# (6, 6)
# (9, 9)
# (4, 4)
# (5, 5)
# (6, 6)
# (9, 9)
```

> Notese que se emplea `in` para verificar que está en la celda `laberinto[i][j]`, ya que una celda también es un arreglo, pero de dimensión `1`, no obstante el `in` puede ser reemplazado por (`==`), quedando `'*' == laberinto[i][j]`

Comment: Si la matriz fuera rectangular sólo hay que reemplazar `for i in range(0, dim):` por `for i in range(0, len(laberinto[j])):`