# Imprimir posiciones de una lista de listas

Tags: python, lista, matrices, python-2.x

Tengo este problema:

> Elabora un programa que genere una matriz de n x n (n solicitado al usuario) cuyas entradas deberán ser números aleatorios en el rango [0-20]. El programa deberá solicitar al usuario un
>   número que esté dentro de ese rango y presentar el renglón y columna de todas las entradas de la matriz que coincidan con ese número.

ya hice la primera parte, pero no tengo idea de como imprimir las posiciones:

```
n=input('Dame n ')
D=[[randint(0,20) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
print 'D='
for i in D:
    for j in i:
        print '%d\t' % j,
    print
```

Comment: Hola Adolfo, lo que necesitas es `enumerate`. La pregunta realmente es un duplicado de [Buscar y obtener coordenadas X e Y de un elemento en una matriz bidimensional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/109191/15089). Lo único que deberías hacer es validar que el número ingresado está dentro del rango 0- 20 en todo caso. En la pregunta enlazada tienes dos formas de hacerlo, `enumerate` (que es la que deberías usar si te dejan, por legibilidad y eficiencia) y usando `range` e indizado. Un saludo.

Comment: No tiene nada que ver con la pregunta, pero no se debe usar `input` para obtener entradas de usuario en python 2, se debe usar `raw_input` y hacer un casting : `n = int(raw_input('Dame n '))`. Mírate [Diferencia entre input() y raw_input()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/38288/15089) . Por otro lado, supongo que al ser una tarea es posible que te obliguen, pero deberías dejar de usar Python 2, no recibe nuevas características desde hace tiempo y en cinco meses deja de tener soporte oficial, y pasarte a Python 3. Aprender usando Python 2.x al que le quedan 5 meses de vida tiene poco sentido.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me sirvió la pregunta a la que me dirigiste, y al parecer ya me salio, solo no entiendo bien como cuenta las coordenadas, si tu sabes te lo agradeceria.

Comment: Y sobre lo de Python 2, ni siquiera sabia que era el 2 o que existía el 3, ¿como me puedo pasar al 3? incluso ni pensé que existieran nuevas características o que ya iba a morir el 2

Comment: A lo primero, `enumerate` simplemente itera sobre un iterable cualquiera  y por cada item retorna una tupla de dos elementos, el primero es la cuenta (el número del elemento empezando a contar desde 0, lo que en una lista equivale a su índice) del item en el iterable y el segundo es el propio item. Es decir para `enumerate(["H", "J"])` generaría `(0, "H")` y `(1, "J")`. Al hacer `for index, item in enumerate([...])` asignamos en cada iteración el indice a la variable `index` y el elemento a la variable `item` (desempaquetado).

Comment: En cuanto a lo segundo, puedes descargarte la versión mas reciente (Python 3.7.4) (3.8 está en beta ahora mismo) desde la propia web oficial de Python: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-374/. No se que sistema operativo usas, dependiendo de ello hay más formas de instalarlo (repositorios oficiales en distros Linux por ejemplo). Para Windows 64 bits este es el enlace de descarga: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/python-3.7.4-amd64.exe